# Mysql Insert on duplicate key update from another table

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have 2 tables in MySQL, one for files and one for nodes. In this case node is a server where the files are stored.

**files** table:

```
id  name        size    nodeid 
===============================
1   doc-file    12354   1
2   mpg-file    300000  1
3   txt-file    150     2
4   doc-file    2544    3
```

**nodes** table

```
id  nodeid   nodesize    numfiles  nodemaxsize
=============================================
1   1        312354      2         20000000
2   2        150         1         20000000
3   3        2544        1         20000000
4   4        0           0         20000000
```

I want to "populate" the table **node** with COUNT( `id` ) and SUM( `size` ) from table **files**. So I need to insert new row if nodeid doesn't exist on table **nodes** with COUNT( `id` ) and SUM( `size` ) from table **files** and default nodemaxsize = MAXSIZE (in this example 20000000) or to update values ( nodesize and numfiles) if nodeid exist.

There is an simple way to insert/update from other another table only with SQL?